# Celery not connecting to Redis broker: Connection to broker lost

Tags: redis, amqp, django-celery, kombu

I'm trying to get Redis to work as a broker for my Celery 3.0.19 install on Django. I see that redis-server is running on port 6379.  When I run a simple Celery test, I get the following stack trace:

```
Ubuntu Lucid 10.0.4
Celery 3.0.19

celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info

[2013-05-02 18:56:27,835: INFO/MainProcess] consumer: Connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0.
[2013-05-02 18:56:27,835: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 394, in start
self.reset_connection()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 744, in reset_connection
self.connection, on_decode_error=self.on_decode_error,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 311, in __init__
**kw
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 355, in __init__
self.revive(self.channel)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 367, in revive
self.declare()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 377, in declare
queue.declare()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 490, in declare
self.queue_declare(nowait, passive=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 516, in queue_declare
nowait=nowait)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/__init__.py", line 404, in queue_declare
return queue, self._size(queue), 0
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 516, in _size
sizes = cmds.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 1919, in execute
return execute(conn, stack, raise_on_error)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 1811, in _execute_transaction
self.parse_response(connection, '_')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 1882, in parse_response
self, connection, command_name, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 387, in parse_response
response = connection.read_response()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 312, in read_response
raise response
ResponseError: unknown command 'MULTI'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need redis version >= 2.2.0.